# YouTube iframe API disable skipping

Tags: youtube-api

Taking a look at the YouTube iFrame API, there appears to be no existing call or state that indicates whether or not a user is trying to skip to some point in a video. Ideally, in my implementation I would either like to disable YouTube controls entirely (which is apparently difficult to do from the perspective of browser-compatibility) or detect when a user is trying to skip, and return him to the point in the video before the attempt to skip was made.

Is there any good way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you'll be disabling the [controls](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#controls) in the iframe, try using the `control = 0`.

```
<iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="720" height="405"
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/?controls=0&list=PLeCdlPO-XhWFzEVynMsmosfdRsIZXhZi0&listType=playlist"
frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
```

For customize player control, try using this tutorial - [How to Control YouTube's Video Player with JavaScript](http://tutorialzine.com/2015/08/how-to-control-youtubes-video-player-with-javascript/).

For example, playback control (Play and Pause):

```
$('#play').on('click', function () {
    player.playVideo();
});

$('#pause').on('click', function () {
    player.pauseVideo();
});
```

Hope this help.